# " Linker command failed with exit code 1 " in unit test?

Tags: ios, xcode

I setup the project by Xcode 8.2.1. I upgrade to Xcode 8.3.2. I can run the project and no error. But when I run the unit test to test my app , I got this problem:

[image]

I have tried some ways to solve it. For example: clean the Test host

[image]

Or remove the derivedData and clean the app. All of them weren't work for me. I don't known the reason why I got this error. Does anyone can help me? Thanks

Comment: Double click on the "Linker Error" will show details and please share those here. Thanks

Comment: @byJeevan. I tried double click on the "Linker error",but nothing show in xcode. I confused about it.

Comment: Looks like a lack of some lib or framework file ， check the error info and reset that file path may solve this problem.

Comment: @Kira. The problem is I can't get more details about the error. I click the error and nothing show to me. So ,  I can't check the error and reset the file path. I tried to quit Xcode and restart it . When I run the app. It's ok. Try to run the unit test , it gets me the same error. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 8):

The Host Application on my Test Target was set to `None` for me the error was resolved when I set that to my Project Target

You can set that in this dropdown in the `General` tab on your project Target:

[image]

Comment: My Host Application said 'Custom'. I changed the Host Application to my actual app, and the build succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the most unhelpful error ever while adding unit tests to an Xcode project.

The issue was that the Podfile was not updated to include a test target. I fixed it with the following steps:

First, get the name of your test target.

Next, update your Podfile with this:

```
  target '<YOUR_PROJECT>Tests' do
      inherit! :search_paths

      # Any pods that may be needed for testing
  end
```

Then, run `pod install`.

After that, I was able to build & run tests.

Your mileage may vary...

Answer (score 0):

If you are here because it seems that you can't see more details about this error, right click and select 'Reveal in Log'.

Answer (score 0):

That happened to me too a couple of times after removing a pod.

I just clean the project (Product --> Clean (Build Folder)) and when rebuilding, the error message is gone.